# Re-allocating cells in rows in columns to equal given row and column sums

Tags: quadratic-programming

Suppose I have a matrix which looks like:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n}\\
a_{21}\\
.\\
a_{n1} &  &  & a_{nn}
\end{array}\right]
$$
where $a_{ij}$ denotes the value of $a$ in row $i$ and column $j.$
For each row $i,$ I have a given constraint on its sum. So, the sum of the first row should be:
$$
\sum_{j}x_{1j}=R_{1}
$$
Similarly, we have it for all other $n-1$ rows. Moreover, I have
another constraint, which for the first column is:
$$
\sum_{i}x_{i1}=C_{1}
$$
These also make up a total of $n$ column constraints. So, I have
$n$ row constraints and $n$ column constraints in this example.
As of now, there is no guarantee that these constraints are being
met. Is there any well known algorithm ( a least squares type?) to re-allocate cells in a manner which doesnt change original data much, but still meets the constraints? This could  take the form of, say:
$$
\text{min}\sum_{ij}\left(a_{ij}-\epsilon\right)^{2}
$$
s.t. the $2N$ row and column constraints? Is there a closed form
solution for this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *matrix balancing* and can be solved via [iterative proportional fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_proportional_fitting).

See Schneider and Zenios, A Comparative Study of Algorithms for Matrix Balancing, *Operations Research* **38** (1990).

Here are two informative blog posts:

- https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2020/09/08/matrix-balancing.html
- https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2020/09/10/iterative-proportional-fitting-sas.html

Comment: any applications of matrix balancing to probability distributions, or marginals of copulae?